# Getting error #110 "There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause." in query with matching columns

Tags: .net, sql-server, prepared-statement

A user of mine in Sweden is reporting an error with a query in my VB.NET app. Error #110 "There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause." He sent over the following blurry screenshot with the error message:

[image: Error 110]

The error message has the following structure:

```
$"DoSql Error #{ex.Number}: {ex.Message}; sql: {sql}; Item={iType}:{iNo}:{iColor}:{iCond}"
```

I'm calling a SQL Server query from VB.NET using a parameterized query with 18 columns being inserted. There is no string interpolation.

```
Private Sub UpdatePrices(iNo As String, iType As String, iColor As Integer, iCond As String)
... 'Retrieve pgonline Json result from web server '
Dim sqlParams = GetParams({
        {"@Item", iNo},
        {"@Color", iColor},
        {"@Cond", iCond},
        {"@Type", iType}},
        {"@Curr", pgOnline("currency_code").ToString},
        {"@SoldMinPrice", pgOnline("min_price").Value(Of Single)},
        {"@SoldMaxPrice", pgOnline("max_price").Value(Of Single)},
        {"@SoldAvgPrice", pgOnline("avg_price").Value(Of Single)},
        {"@SoldQtyAvgPrice", pgOnline("qty_avg_price").Value(Of Single)},
        {"@SoldLotQty", Math.Min(32767, pgOnline("unit_quantity").Value(Of Integer))},
        {"@SoldItemQty", Math.Min(32767, pgOnline("total_quantity").Value(Of Integer))},
        {"@StockMinPrice", pgOnline("min_price").Value(Of Single)},
        {"@StockMaxPrice", pgOnline("max_price").Value(Of Single)},
        {"@StockAvgPrice", pgOnline("avg_price").Value(Of Single)},
        {"@StockQtyAvgPrice", pgOnline("qty_avg_price").Value(Of Single)},
        {"@StockLotQty", pgOnline("unit_quantity").Value(Of Integer)},
        {"@StockItemQty", Math.Min(32767, pgOnline("total_quantity").Value(Of Integer))}
            }))
Dim sql = "INSERT INTO [Bricklink].[Price_Guide] (PriceDate,ItemNo,ItemType,Color,Cond,Curr,SoldMinPrice,SoldMaxPrice,SoldAvgPrice,SoldQtyAvgPrice,
  SoldLotQty,  SoldItemQty,  StockMinPrice,  StockMaxPrice,  StockAvgPrice,  StockQtyAvgPrice,  StockLotQty,  StockItemQty) 
VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @Item, @Type, @Color, @Cond, @Curr, @SoldMinPrice, @SoldMaxPrice, @SoldAvgPrice, @SoldQtyAvgPrice, 
  @SoldLotQty, @SoldItemQty, @StockMinPrice, @StockMaxPrice, @StockAvgPrice, @StockQtyAvgPrice, @StockLotQty, @StockItemQty);"
DoSql(sql, sqlParams, True)
```

There are 18 columns in both the Insert statement and the Values clause.  The parameters are a mix of .NET numerics of Single or Integer type. This data is retrieved from a server - when I pull the data from the US, the Single values (prices) will have no thousands separator and 3 decimal places.

It is important to note that I have never received this error myself - this price update query runs thousands of times a day for me. The user in Sweden is one of only a couple of Non-US users. I believe that something that is different about either how the data is structured for the user in Sweden or how his computer interprets that data is causing SQL Server to misread the numbers. My hunch was that a comma in the data value would make the query think it was a field separator, leading it to think there were more columns in Values than the Insert

But when I experiment on my computer with changing the dot to a comma to see how my PC reacts, the only error I can get is an arithmetic overflow. It does not mistake the comma in the value for a comma in the query. Also when there is no sales data, the server returns 0 for all fields, not nulls or blanks.

1. Is it possible for parameters to behave this way?
2. If so, how do I correct for it in the query?
3. If not, what difference could there be that would cause SQL Server to think this query with 18 columns in Insert and 18 columns in Values is something else?

Appendix: For those looking for the code calling the query - I've posted the DoSql code below.

```
Public Function DoSql(sql As String, Optional ByVal params As List(Of SqlParameter) = Nothing, Optional throwException As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(GetDBConnectionString)
        Return DoSql(conn, sql, params, throwException)
    End Using
End Function
Public Function DoSql(conn As SqlConnection, sql As String, Optional ByVal params As List(Of SqlParameter) = Nothing, Optional throwException As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    If Not IsNothing(params) Then
        For Each param In params
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param)
        Next
    End If
    If cmd.Connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then cmd.Connection.Open()
    Try
        Dim rows As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        Return (rows > 0)
    Catch ex As SqlException
        Dim paramStg As String = ""
        If params IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each param In params
                paramStg += param.ParameterName & "=" & param.Value.ToString & "; "
            Next
        End If
        Log($"DoSql Error {ex.Number}: {ex.Message} executing: {sql} with params={paramStg}", 2)
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        If throwException Then Throw ex
        MsgBoxASync($"DoSql Error #{ex.Number}: {ex.Message}; parameters: {paramStg}; sql: {sql}")
        Return False
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim paramStg As String = ""
        If params IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each param In params
                paramStg += param.ParameterName & "=" & param.Value.ToString & "; "
            Next
        End If
        Log($"Error {ex.Message} occured executing the DoSQL command {sql} with params={paramStg}", 2)
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: One difference could be decimal comma versus  decimal dot. But how that would affect your posted query, I don't know - if you really use parameters all the way

Comment: Could post VB code calling this query?

Comment: Could the error actually be coming from a trigger?

Comment: Not possible for that to happen because of parameters. Is there perhaps a hidden character in the text (copy paste into a hex editor directly from your code editor) I can't see anything in the code you gave use but perhaps it didn't copy correctly. Please also post the client app VB code

Comment: I've added additional b.net code - including where I create the parameters and also how the DoSql function works. I don't have access to the user's computer or the text. I didn't even understand how this error occurred, frankly. My next step is to release an update with additional extensive logging and hopefully the user will let it crash and send his log to me.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Can you explain the trigger?

Comment: Sure, you could have an insert [trigger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) that generates a dynamic insert using `inserted`. Check if there are any triggers on `Price_Guide` and try disabling them and running the insert again. We can all count and it's clear the problem isn't in front of us so must be somewhere else. It could also be in `Log` which you are calling inside `CATCH` - does it insert something? Any chance the code there has changed? Could the user have an outdated version of your application that isn't the same as what you show here?

Comment: (It's also possible that if you reuse variables like `{sql}` that an error is being reported but is being associated with the wrong `{sql}`, or the error is happening on a different statement that maybe doesn't even use `{sql}` but the error handling is still using that variable name. There are just so many possibilities here trying to debug a remote app based on a screenshot, I don't know that we can really help you other than wild guesses.)

Comment: I think the error is happening on a different statement that I called directly and did not assign to the variable sql!!  Thank you for your wild guesses!